# Connection between the area of a n-sphere and the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: geometry, riemann-zeta, spheres

The [Riemann Xi-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Xi-Function.html) is defined as
$$
\xi(s) = \tfrac{1}{2} s(s-1) \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2} s\right) \zeta(s)
$$
and it satisfies the reflection formula
$$
\xi(s) = \xi(1-s).
$$
But the area $A$ of a [$s$-dimensional sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) is 
$$
A(s) = \frac{2 \pi^{s/2}}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2} s\right)}
$$
so that we can write the Xi-Function like
$$
\xi(s) = s(s-1) \frac{\zeta(s)}{A(s)}.
$$
If we insert this into the reflection formula we get the following relation between the area of a n-sphere and the Riemann zeta function
$$
\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = \frac{A(s)}{A(1-s)}
$$
Has this relation been noted in the literature? Why should there be such a connection between the area of a n-sphere and the zeta function? Can this relation be explained geometrically?

UPDATE: I agree with the comments that negative dimensional spheres are difficult to interpret geometrically. However if we insert the formula for the area $A$ into [Eulers reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)= \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}
$$
we get
$$
A(1-s) = \frac{4\sin\left(\pi \frac{s+1}{2}\right)}{A(s+1)}
$$
Inserting this into our relation with the Riemann zeta function yields
$$
\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = \frac{A(s)A(s+1)}{4\sin\left(\pi \frac{s+1}{2}\right)}
$$
which avoids the negative dimensions for $s>0$. Can this formula be interpreted geometrically?

Comment: *Why should there be such a connection between the area of a n-sphere and the zeta function ?* - What is a sphere ? A bounded sum of powers: $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2.~$ And what is the $\zeta$ function ? A bounded sum of powers: recall its famous infinite series expression for $\Re(s)>1.~$ And by expanding the power of a sum into a sum of powers through Newton's binomial series we get binomial coefficients, *aka* beta functions, which can be expressed in terms of factorials, *aka* $\Gamma$ functions. In general, all $\Gamma$ functions of argument $\frac1n$ are connected to superellipses $x^n+y^n=r^n$.

Comment: I can't follow you. You are saying e.g. $\zeta(3) = \frac{1}{1^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + ...$ is a bounded sum of powers? It is a bounded sum, but it is a sum with infinite terms to the power 3. Whereas a 3d-sphere is a bounded sum of three terms to the power two. Can you elaborate again on what kind of connection you see between these sum of powers?

Comment: The [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) $x^n+y^n=r^n$ has an area which is directly expressible in terms of beta$/\Gamma$ functions, whose arguments are rational numbers of denominator *n*. At the same time, $\zeta(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^n}.~$ Both are bounded sums of powers. For instance, the fact that $\Gamma\Big(\tfrac12\Big)=\sqrt\pi$ and $\zeta(2n)=a_n\cdot\pi^n$ are both related to the the same fundamental constant is not a coincidence. Since $A(s)$ is expressible in terms of $\Gamma(s),$ the conclusion follows.

Comment: What geometrical meaning do you give to $A(-\frac 1 2)$ and $A(\textrm i)$?

Comment: I don't think you can hope for a simple geometrical interpretation of this. Saying that $A(s)$ is the area of a sphere only makes sense when $s$ is an integer (the dimension of the space). But if $s$ is an integer then $1-s$ is negative (or zero) so there are no choices where both $A(s)$ and $A(1-s)$ can be given a classical geometrical interpretation.

Comment: Could it be that negative dimensions can be interpreted as switching from a right-handed coordinate system to a left handed coordinate system? This would be in analogy to the theory of determinants, where a determinant is negative if the orientation of the basis changes.

Answer (score 9):

The relation $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{A(s)}=\frac{\zeta(1-s)}{A(1-s)}$$ stems from the fact that $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{A(s)}=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{M}\left(\psi\right)\left(\frac{s}{2}\right),$$ where $\mathcal{M}$ denotes the Mellin transform and $$\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}.$$ This function is symmetric due to the functional equation for $\psi(x)$, and that yields the functional equation for the zeta function. The reason for the connection to the surface area appears in my previous answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1494471/6075, which provides a geometric explanation for integer dimensions - the case where we can actually interpret the surface area. In that answer, I showed that the factor of $A(s)$ appears due to the spherical symmetry of a naturally arising $s$-dimensional integral expression for $\zeta(s)$.

**Remark 1:** This gives an excellent way to remember the precise form of the functional equation!

**Remark 2:** Note that the surface area here, $A(s)$, corresponds to the $s-1$-dimensional sphere, that is the surface of the $s$-dimensional ball, whereas in the linked answer, $A_{k-1}$ is the surface area of the $k-1$-dimensional sphere, that is the surface of the $k$ dimensional ball.